# Why do I receive two SIGCONT signals?

Tags: c, signals, zsh

I'm writing a program that sets terminal attributes so I have to reset the terminal any time the script exits, including if the user presses ^Z, but when I re-enter the command with fg, the SIGCONT signal gets sent two times, but I'm only expecting it to be called 1 time. Why is it happening twice? Here is a short program that shows the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sigtstp (int signum) {
    write(1, "got a SIGTSTP\n", 14);
    kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
}

void sigcont (int signum) {
    write(1, "got a SIGCONT\n", 14);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    signal(SIGTSTP, sigtstp);
    signal(SIGCONT, sigcont);
    while (1) {
        sleep(100);
    }
}
```

output is like this:

```
% clang cont.c -o cont
% ./cont
^Zgot a SIGTSTP
zsh: suspended (signal)  ./cont
% fg
[5]    continued  ./cont
got a SIGCONT
got a SIGCONT
^C
```

I'm using zsh on macOS.

Comment: FWIW, I ran your code on macOS and could not reproduce the problem. Do you get the same behaviour all the time? Calling `printf` in a signal handler is technically undefined behaviour as it is not async safe. Trying calling `write` instead to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: it doesn't happen on bash, only zsh for me. and sometimes one SIGCONT signal is received but most of the time it's two. try several ^Z, fg, ^Z, fg in a row, it might trigger it. I replaced the printf's above with writes and I still see it.

Comment: Testing on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (don't ask!) I  also cannot reproduce the double signal.  I was using a `zsh` that I simply ran as `zsh` (from a Bash prompt), not a login shell, but that's unlikely to be the cause of the difference.  One difference: I got `[1]` instead of `[5]`.  Did you have a bunch of processes left over that all got the signal?  Again, I can't reproduce it running your program twice and suspending them both.  But the `[5]` suggests you have a lot of jobs around, and that may be a factor.  Try looking at the output of `jobs`.

Comment: It happens even if I start from a new terminal window, where I would get [1]  in the "continued" message. I'm running zsh version 5.7.1 on macOS 10.15.6

Comment: How about to use `kill -s SIGCONT <pid>` to send signal to see if there is any difference since it looks like a zsh issue as per the tests and comments above.

Comment: sending the signal explicitly will cause the signal handler to only execute once as expected, so it must be something with my zsh configuration causing this.

Comment: Thank you very much for this post, and your useful test program. This problem was driving me crazy on Ubuntu 22.04 -- at random times, `fg` would fail to restore my stopped `vim` jobs. Using `strace` I noticed an extra SIGCONT being sent to `vim`. That led me to your post, which gave me a reproducible test case. What a relief, thank you so much. The fix is to install zsh 5.9 or patch your zsh with Erik Paulson's fix linked in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in zsh versions 5.7, 5.7.1, 5.8, and 5.8.1. It was fixed by Erik Paulson for zsh 5.9:

https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2021/msg01255.html

On Ubuntu 20.04 - 22.04 this zsh bug causes `fg` to sometimes fail to restore a stopped `vim`. For some unknown reason the extra SIGCONT causes `vim` to immediately stop itself again.